# How to change the iOS Simulator "window background color" (Full Screen, Xcode 10, Mojave, Dark Mode)

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode10, macos-mojave, macos-darkmode

Mojave (macOS 10.14) is great.
Xcode 10.0 (10A254a) is great.
[Dark Mode](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/visual-design/dark-mode/) is great.

What is not so great, unless I'm missing something, is this ugly gray background of the iOS simulator window (when in **full screen**):

[image: iOSSimulatorDarkMode]

> **Any idea on how to change that color?**

Comment: Please do let me know if you ever get an answer updated for Mojave as I do want to change the same property :)

Comment: Within the simulator device's files there is a SpringBoard folder containing `LockBackgroundThumbnail.jpg` & `LockBackground.cpbitmap` files.  Despite the filenames, could it be these are also used for the background image after unlock?    `/Users/YourUserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/TheSimulatorDeviceID/data/Library/SpringBoard/`

Comment: Unfortunately these are irrelevant as I'm trying to change the color of the `simulator window` -- not the contents "inside" the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody still struggles with this here is somewhat a solution: toggle "Show Device Bezels" in the window menu of the simulator will do the trick. However this needs to be done each time the simulator is started....

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer you seek.

Boot into recovery mode (Cmd+R while booting) and then open the Terminal.

1. `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD` //if your drive is named something different, replace accordingly
2. `csrutil disable` //disables System Integrity Protection
3. `mkdir AppleInternal` //activates testing and custom commands in Apple apps, including Simulator
4. `csrutil enable` //re-enable System Integrity Protection
5. `reboot` //back to regular environment

Now there's an "Internal" menu in the Simulator. In here, you can change loads of settings including the window's background color. It uses the regular OS X colour picker so you can even choose a hex code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I tried, but unfortunately the `Internal` menu doesn't show up. The folder was created successfully. It is working for you in Mojave? It looks like that hidden feature got removed in Mojave: https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXTweaks/comments/99vebr/appleinternal_folder_is_created_but_no_internals/ Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this (I'm on Catalina 10.15.7): Change your desktop background to the desired color. The simulator adapts to the color with a different opacity (or alpha?!) value when in fullscreen mode.